# Issue with blank entry in array

Tags: vba, excel

I have an array that can either have 6 or 7 values, the code below shows how I can have 6 or 7 values:

```
Dim AB(1 To 7)

AB(1) = "1-P"
AB(2) = "1-L"
AB(3) = "1-E"
AB(4) = "1-I"
AB(5) = "1-O"
AB(6) = "1-T"
If TeachingTool.teacherInPlYes = True Then
    AB(7) = "1-R"
End If
```

Once the array has been populated I search the current sheet for the calues in the array and populate a listbox with there cell positions, however because there is a blank space in the array it pulls me back alot of unwanted data for some reason and I can't figure out why. I have tried use `Dim AB(1 To 6 or 7)` but that didn't work. So some information on this issue would be helpful, thanks

Comment: Dim as `dim ab() as string` Not saying how big makes it a dynamic array. The `as String` part is optional. You need to read it in help. See `Redim` plus the conceptual topic `Dynamic Arrays`.

Comment: Create a dynamic array with redim. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/w8k3cys2.aspx

Comment: If you use a Dictionary or Collection you won't have to worry about how big it is. Arrays are an old concept (memory efficient but not that flexible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ReDim`. That way you can dimension the array accordingly. Example:

```
If TeachingTool.teacherInPlYes = True Then
    ReDim AB(1 To 7)
    AB(7) = "1-R"
Else
    ReDim AB(1 to 6)
End If
AB(1) = "1-P"
AB(2) = "1-L"
AB(3) = "1-E"
AB(4) = "1-I"
AB(5) = "1-O"
AB(6) = "1-T"
```